# ENS function startAuctionsAndBid

Tags: web3js, ens

I've been working with ens via `web3.js` and `ensutils.js` but I'm stuck at  `startAuctionsAndBid` function.

If I try :

```
var sbid = ethRegistrar.shaBid(web3.sha3('name'), eth.accounts[8], web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether'), web3.sha3('my secret phrase'))
ethRegistrar.startAuctionsAndBid(0x12345670159e0506114fee112628a969f587bf4b7bf4a728661705c08fa9ce82, sbid);
```

I'm getting:

```
TypeError: 'forEach' is not a function
    at web3.js:1553:13
    at web3.js:694:16
    at map (<native code>)
    at web3.js:693:20
    at web3.js:4059:46
    at web3.js:4130:19
    at apply (<native code>)
    at web3.js:4223:16
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Other functions, like `startAuction`, `newBid`, `unsealBid` work as expected,  only `startAuctionsAndBid` gives me an error.
Any idea why?

---

**Update**:

The `forEach` error was fixed by providing an `array` as first argument. 
The function is now executed but it [fails on contract execution](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xaf11f548019c2a904bc209cb43ca8c9b3c5bd546a39507901f7dec7a63f41913)

`startAuctionsAndBid` expects 2 arguments:

```
hashes bytes32[]
sealedBid bytes32
```

How can I construct the elements of the `hashes` array?
I tried `hashes = [web3.sha3('name')]`, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have need to quote addresses as must be strings. The Javascript VM will not support such large numbers natively.

```
ethRegistrar.startAuctionsAndBid("0x12345670159e0506114fee112628a969f587bf4b7bf4a728661705c08fa9ce82", sbid);
```

Comment: hi there, it's quoted, `hashes = [web3.sha3('name')]` - `["0x12345db9720459d9b81668541cd4d26e42a037017ab1b813996a0d03926bf68"]`

Answer (score 0):

There might be two issues in your code,

1. startAuctionsAndBid() is not return any value/non array value. Check once.
2. startAuctionsAndBid(**0x12345670159e0506114fee112628a969f587bf4b7bf4a728661705c08fa9ce82**, sbid); Javascipt will convert 1st argument to equivalent integer. Js may not not hold that much of integer. So please add single or double quotes.